# Why does nothing happen when I run this macro on excel VBA? Am I missing something?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Delete_Multiple_Rows() 
        'delete multiple rows (rows 2,3,4,5)
         [Worksheets("sheets 7"). Range ("2:5"). EntireRow. Delete]
End Sub
```

I am trying to delete rows 2-5

Comment: What's with the brackets?

Comment: What is the output you get? Is the second line not missing a `'`?

Answer (score 3):

The `[ ]` are a shortcut to the `Evaluate` method.  So what goes in there has to be someting that works as an Excel Formula.

But, that's not what you want.  Remove the `[ ]` and the extranious spaces, to get

```
Worksheets("sheets 7").Range("2:5").EntireRow.Delete
```

Now, *if* the active workbook has a sheet called `sheets 7` then it will work and delete rows 2 to 5

But, since you already specified Rows, the `.EntireRow` bit is not needed, this is just as good

```
Worksheets("sheets 7").Range("2:5").Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need 'EntireRow' property. it s enough to use:

```
 Worksheets("sheets 7".Rows("2:5").Delete
```